# Is there a way to spin an image in 3d using css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have three image files in an HTML div tag. I need those images to show one at a time. When one image appears it stays for a few seconds then spins (like a spinning coin) and after the spin animation is complete, the second image should take its place. Hold-Spin again-Third image. And this should be in a loop.

Comment: Yes, there is. .

Comment: Try to always assume there is a way, make some searches, and try some attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the transform: rotateZ() property and delay its starting time by transform: translate(1s).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use transform property

transform :  rotateZ();

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform